# How to encrypt password in Django from the server side

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I am wondering how I can encrpyt the password

I am PUT from the REST API. I want my code to do something like this

Views.py

```
#Users Viewset
class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    m = Users(username=restapibodyusername, email=restapibodyenmail, password=make_password(pwdrestapibodypassword)
    serializer_class = UsersSerializer
```

Seralizer.py

```
# Users Seralizer
class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = '__all__'
```

I can encrypt it in the client side but I prefer to do it in the serverside. Is this even possible?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to not return passwords, encrypted or not in your API?

Comment: @IainShelvington Oh sorry, I meant PUT. my bad. Edited

Comment: This is an API to login/create a user? So long as you are using HTTPS/SSL, the data being sent from the client to the backend will be encrypted.

Comment: Its an api to register a user. In my database, my password is not encrypted when i run the PUT command. I am wondering how i can store a encrypted password. Thanks for the help @IainShelvington

Comment: When creating a user in Django you should nearly always use [`User.objects.create_user()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) as it handles encrypting the password for you. You may have to override the create method of your viewset to call this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# you have to import make_password

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

# If you are using PUT request, then you can write update function in your serializer

def update(self, instance, validatedData):
    # get the password and hash it
    password = validatedData.get("password", instance.password)
    hash_password = make_password(password)

    instance.username = validatedData.get("username", instance.username)
    instance.email = validatedData.get("email", instance.email)
    instance.password = hash_password

    instance.save()

    return instance
```

Comment: Hi, I am having trouble trying to insert your code into mine, I updated my post to show you my seralizer. Do i put the def update inside the class MEta?

Comment: Kmuar Thanks it worked! I am wondering how would I do it for a POST request instead of PUT?

Comment: If you want to write a function for POST request, then you can write 'create' function in your serializer.